# How to mock method of instance of module with Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Test-connection.ts file is:

```
import { IEnvironmentMap, load } from 'dotenv-extended';
import { getTokensWithAuthCode, sdk } from '../src/connection-manager';

describe('Box API connection tests', () => {

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    let boxConfig: IEnvironmentMap;

    beforeAll(() => {
        boxConfig = load({
            errorOnMissing: true,
        });
    });

    describe('getTokensWithAuthCode function Tests', () => {

        it('should reject a promise if there is wrong auth code provided', async () => {
            jest.mock('box-node-sdk', () => ({
                 getTokensAuthorizationCodeGrant: jest.fn(),
            }));

            await getTokensWithAuthCode();
            expect(sdk.getTokensAuthorizationCodeGrant).toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
   });
});
```

This is my main program file 
Connection.ts

```
import * as BoxSDK from 'box-node-sdk';
import { IEnvironmentMap, load } from 'dotenv-extended';
import {ITokenInfo} from '../typings/box-node-sdk';

const boxConfig: IEnvironmentMap = load({
     errorOnMissing: true,
});

export const sdk: BoxSDK = new BoxSDK({
     clientID: boxConfig.BOX_CLIENT_ID,
     clientSecret: boxConfig.BOX_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

export async function getTokensWithAuthCode() {

    return await new Promise((resolve: (tokenInfo: ITokenInfo) => void, reject: (err: Error) => void) => {

        sdk.getTokensAuthorizationCodeGrant(boxConfig.BOX_AUTH_CODE, null, (err: Error, tokenInfo: ITokenInfo) => {
            if (err !== null) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(tokenInfo);
       });
});
}
```

When ran as `jest --coverage`, it is throwing error. I suspect it is due to wrong mock. Can you help with correct implementation of the mock for this module with jest?

Comment: I've tried this in the past and I couldn't get it to work. I vaguely remember about it. I guess it might work if you use `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: I tried that, it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mocking itself is correct, but order is incorrect. `import` statement is static and hoisted in top level only - so `getTokensWithAuthCode` is imported first with original `box-node-sdk` module. Then mocking won't effect as loaded module doesn't refresh internally loaded dependencies.

Couple of ways to solve this.

1. using babel-jest, hoist mocking to top level. then even with import statement, your mock will be hoisted before importing it. for example

   ```
   import {getTokensWithAuthCode} ...
   jest.mock('box-node-sdk' ...);
   ```

   will be correctly ordered into

   ```
   jest.mock('box-node-sdk' ...);
   const {getTokensWithAuthCode} = require(...) //transpiled
   ```

   `ts-jest` does this for you if you're using TypeScript.
2. Dynamically requires `getTokensWithAuthCode` in each test fixture after mocking your dependencies.

Both of them is about ordering mocks and real import - key thing in here is you *should* mock first either using tool or manually.